# CommunicationException- failed to unmarshel Remote business interface looking up ejb3 in weblogic

Tags: interface, weblogic, ejb-3.0, jndi

My ejb 3 classes and remote interface are as follows :

```
package com.myeclipse.ejb3;

import java.io.Serializable;

public interface IMyBean extends Serializable 
{
  public void doSomething();
}
```

Remote interface:

```
package com.myeclipse.ejb3;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface MyBeanRemote extends IMyBean {

}
```

Stateless ejb:

```
package com.myeclipse.ejb3;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless(mappedName="ejb/MyBean")
public class MyBean implements MyBeanRemote 
{
public void doSomething()
{
    System.out.println("Hello world");
}
}
```

Project is successully deployed as a jar file in weblogic. I developed
a standalone client to call ejb. But this is failing. Kindly help.
I've included all the weblogic server libraries to connect to jndi and
remote business interface for complilation.

Client Code :

```
package Ejb3_Client;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class MyBeanClient {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try { 

         Properties p = new Properties();

         p.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
         p.put("java.naming.provider.url", "t3://172.21.123.70:8001");

         InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(p);         

        MyBeanRemote bean = (MyBeanRemote) ctx.lookup("ejb/MyBean#com.myeclipse.ejb3.MyBeanRemote"); 
        System.out.println("bean instance "+ bean); 
        bean.doSomething(); 
         System.out.println("bean worked");

    } catch (NamingException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 


}

}
```

But I am getting this exception:

> javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is
>   java.rmi.UnmarshalException: failed to unmarshal class
>   java.lang.Object; nested exception is: 
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myeclipse.ejb3.MyBeanRemote]
>     at
>   weblogic.jndi.internal.ExceptionTranslator.toNamingException(ExceptionTranslator.java:74)
>     at
>   weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.translateException(WLContextImpl.java:439)
>     at
>   weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:395)
>     at
>   weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:380)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)  at
>   Ejb3_Client.MyBeanClient.main(MyBeanClient.java:33) Caused by:
>   java.rmi.UnmarshalException: failed to unmarshal class
>   java.lang.Object; nested exception is: 
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myeclipse.ejb3.MyBeanRemote   at
>   weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:244)     at
>   weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:348)
>     at
>   weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:259)
>     at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode_1030_WLStub.lookup(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:392)
>     ... 3 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.myeclipse.ejb3.MyBeanRemote   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)     at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.readObject(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:200)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1849)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1947)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1871)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:197)
>     at
>   weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.readObject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:564)
>     at
>   weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:193)
>     at weblogic.rmi.internal.ObjectIO.readObject(ObjectIO.java:62)  at
>   weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:240)     ...
>   7 more
>
> I searched a lot but din find the problem why it can't unmarshel remote interface.

Comment: Your code looks correct based on what I see here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/443061/EJB-JEE/java/world-EJB So the way you deployed the jar file is probably incorrect. Can you describe how it was deployed? Does it show as `Active` in the Deployments area of the weblogic console?

Comment: @better_user_mkstemp    Yes,it was active and no error.However , i made it working.by keeping the client class in same package as the package of my stateless bean is..

Comment: Good - if you want you can post your solution as an answer so others see it rather than having to read thru the comments.

Comment: tell me how to post the question as answer and how to tick the right mark on it as i have seen on other questions which are answered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

the reason for above error mainly because in some java file which implements Serializable interface has been changed you can revert those files to previous version